# Bash perpetually generates child processes and cannot be stopped. What is happening?

Tags: bash

In Kubuntu 20.04 or KNOPPIX 9.1, in KDE under Konsole many windows and in each bash ver 5.2.15(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu).

The problem describe in this question I had come up often in the last few weeks (but never before).

Always it is caused by a wrong command line in a sourced script or typed after shell prompt.

Sometimes (not today) bash endlessly forks new processes.

Today I can report the false command line which is the cause -- it is not literally what I typed, it is what ps shows:

```
ps -Flwwc -t pts/14
```

ps shows in column "CMD":

```
sed -r eval s=(.*)=\1; ZZZZZZZZZ;=p /root/.bash_history
```

Please note that this false command is not the item of my question (I know what I am trying and what the next steps are).

The item is, what the crazy bash does and what the help is.

bash shows these two lines in an endless succession:

```
sh -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('

sh -c: line 1: `val s=(.*)=1; ZZZZZZZZZ;=p'
```

In another terminal's bash I run

```
ps -Flwwc --sort=start_time -t pts/14
```

and I see that two child processes are active:

1. `sed` (as shown above)
2. `less`

The PPID of both is the broken bash.

In the broken bash there is no means. E.g.

Typing <kbd>Return</kbd> brings less with its contents. Closing less, I am in the bash prompt, as if all would be ok. And in the other terminal `ps -Flwwc ...` shows as if all would be ok: the two child processes are vanished, the bottom process is the broken bash.

Now back in the broken bash: if I type <kbd>Return</kbd> or if I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, I get the endless sequence of the two lines and in the other terminal `ps -Flwwc ...` shows the two child processes again.

Also if from another terminal in a while loop via `writevt` I send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> etc. in a shortest possible succession, no help.

There is no way to stop the crasy bash in a normal manner.

The only way I know is to kill the broken bash. But this causes to loose the bash history.

( for other applications I use bash PROMPT_COMMAND ... to make `history -a`, but that is not the item here).

Does someone know the reason for this behavior of bash and how to prevent this new behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Found explanation and solution:

In last times I am making experiments with various kinds of PROMPT_COMMAND in order into the history file additionally `/dev/pts/nn` to be written.

The wrong code was a component of the PROMPT_COMMAMD in test.

Thus after killing the child processes it seems all to be normal, indeed all was normal.

When then in the broken bash I gave something that caused a new prompt, the wrong code was execuded within the PROMPT_COMMAND. And thus the child processes were created again, etc.

The solution is: to give the broken bash the command

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND
```

Then the "craziness" of bash ceases.

So I could delete my question. But I do not because some points are worth to be read by others, especially one point should remain public:

It is important to have in Linux the command `writevt`. It should be re-invented to be normal command of every Linux distribution.

Comment: Decent self-solved question.